# Why is it possible to load types in an unsigned assembly from a signed assembly using reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies, strongname

I have two assemblies A and B. A is strong named and B is not.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx) I cannot reference B from A because a strong named assembly can only reference another strong named assembly.

But then why is it possible to load assembly B, instantiate its class and call their methods from assembly A using reflection?

```
// Inside assembly A
Assembly b = Assembly.LoadFrom("B");
obj myObj = b.CreateInstance("MyClass");
```

Doesn't this defeat the very purpose of not allowing to reference unsigned assemblies in a signed one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you have to understand that strong-named assemblies are designed to circumvent "DLL Hell" and allow "side-by-side versioning".  AFAIK it is not designed for security.

Therefore, you're allowed to use reflection in a strong-named assembly to call methods and instantiate classes in unsigned assemblies.  The framework assumes you know what you're doing because you're explicitly loading a file -- and you therefore should know which file you really want.  In other words, you are telling the framework: "For this assembly, I want to manage my own versioning."

Comment: There definitely is a security component to a Strong-named assembly see [What's the Difference, Part Five: certificate signing vs strong naming](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx).  Basically it allows you to confirm the identity of an assembly. Without that malware could easily replace a trusted assembly. Also the OP must use a *fully trusted assembly* not just a strongly named one to create instances using reflection.